# pdflatex (command not found) on terminal for mac

Tags: texshop, terminal-output

I just started college and this is our first assignment so please be patient with explaining this to me, guys. I've been trying to compile what I made on TeXShop but all I got is

```
-bash: pdflatex command not found
```

What do I do?

Comment: Did you install a TeX system (MacTeX, as you are presumably using a Mac based on 'TeXShop')?

Comment: What does the command `ls /usr/texbin/pdflatex` tell you?

Comment: Is there a `which` command on Mac OS too? If yes, then try `which pdflatex`. It should show the position of pdflatex then

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is seemingly due to missing installation of a TeX system

Comment: It does seam the users has an issue with a missing package for Tex. I would not consider "off-topic".  Many times new users have 'simple' pitfalls or misunderstandings.  Closing the topic does not help new users progress. The question "What do i do?" has straight forward and practice answers, as outlined by the help center.

Consider the fallowing:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55438#55438 

Its probably more appropriate to close as duplicate question and then point them to the duplicate so they can find help.